# If feasible region and objective function are the same, are all points in the feasible region optimal?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

If the objective function we try to minimize for example is a line, or hyperplane for example. And the feasibility is also a line or a hyperplane. Does this mean that every point in this line (if there are no other constraints) is an optimal solution of the objective function?
For example, say we want to minimize:
cT.x
where cT = [1 1]
and the constraints are:
Ax=b
x>=0
where A=[1 1]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The feasible region and objective function can't be the same. The objective function must be a function whose domain is the feasible region, and thus even if you view the function as its graph, it will lie in a space that has one extra dimension. Also, every point in the feasible region is optimal if and only if the objective function is constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question requires clarification, considering that the objective function is a real valued function and the admissible region is a set. So, strictly speaking, they are not comparable objects  and your question does not really make sense. I guess you are thinking of situations like

\begin{align*}
\max \,\,\,& x+y\\
\textrm{s.t.}\,\,\, & x+y = 1
\end{align*}

In a case like this, it is true that the optimal solution is attained at every point in the admissible region.